# ¿Cómo agregar imagen a un QPushButton para poder editar su tamaño?

Tags: c++, qt, botón

Tengo que agregar una imagen a un button, pero a la hora de agregarla mediante el icon en la barra de properties no me deja editar el tamaño, el cual es 16x16 de forma predeterminada y quisiera saber cómo agregarla y poder editar su tamaño.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La propiedad `iconSize` no es editable directamente porque es una propiedad compuesta (ancho * alto). Sin embargo estas dos unidades más simples sí que pueden ser editadas. Si te fijas, verás que la propiedad `iconSize` tiene una flecha negra a la izquierda... si haces click con el ratón se desplegarán sus propiedades individuales, las cuales sí podrás editar para configurar el tamaño de la imagen.